# What is causing /user/*/taxonomy/term/* to redirect to /taxonomy/term/*?

Tags: 7, views, redirection, uri

I got a view with contextual filters set up as the following:

- Global: Null (Fixed value "user")
- Content: Author uid (User ID from URL)
- Global: Null (Fixed value "taxonomy")
- Global: Null (Fixed value "term")
- Content: Has taxonomy term ID (Taxonomy term ID from URL)

When I go to `mysite.com/user/*/taxonomy/term/*` I'm being redirected to `mysite.com/taxonomy/term/*`.

How can I prevent this?

I also got Pathauto to change the URLs to `[user:name]` for `user/*` and `tags/[term:name]`for `taxonomy/term/*`.

Edit: If I disable the URL alias for the taxonomy terms it still redirects to `mysite.com/taxonomy/term/*`.

Comment: The redirect cannot be because of the contextual filters. The redirect has been done by some other piece of custom code I guess.

Comment: It must be either Drupal core or Pathauto I guess, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Why cant you change the path to `mysite.com/user-profile/*/taxonomy/term/*`? By default the /user path has lots to do with. Create a custom path of yours and give a try.

Comment: I want the user paths to be mysite.com/[user:name], which means I could change the path in the view to `mysite.com/[user:name]/taxonomy/term/*` or even `mysite.com/[user:name]/tags/[term:name]` but then I'd have to get the Author and Taxonomy Term **Name** instead of the **ID**, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you determined what is causing the redirect in the first place?  That is really your first step.  Any solution is a wild guess until you figure out why this is happening.

Comment: While is probably not causing the redirect, using [user:name] as path alias for the user profile pages is surely going to cause conflicts in the case the username is admin, user, node, or any other word already used in a path from any module.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've set user restrictions to deny any type of username that would cause these kind of conflicts.

Comment: @MPD I disabled Pathauto and the view for the `mysite.com/taxonomy/term/*` page and it still redirects, which means, Drupal core is causing this?

Comment: Also, when I change the path to e.g. `mysite.com/user/*/x/*` or something other than `taxonomy/term` the user page shows up, but without the content (which worked in the views preview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the redirect could be essentially any module you have, and several modules allow for configuration that will cause redirects as well. You will need find the source of the redirect on for your particular situation.

Suggestions:

1. Deactivate modules in a 50 / 50 manner. This allows you to quickly narrow down which module is providing the redirect, and hopefully that will help you to work it out. Using drush to disable/enable modules will make this much faster.
2. Install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel). It has a settings called "Display redirection page", and implements `devel_drupal_goto_alter` halting the redirection.

   The primary purpose of this is to gather up debug information that would otherwise go lost due to the redirect. In this particular case, I suggest you add a `dpm(debug_backtrace());` into the hook so you can trace the call to the source of the redirect.
3. Everything else failing, fire up a full debugger, and trace the call, ideally with help from the information provided by the `debug_backtrace()` above.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by making the view a little bit different than above. I will accept this answer though since it's probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Implement hook_drupal_goto_alter() in a module and

a) put a breakpoint on code in this function and view the call-stack to determine which function is setting the redirect in the first place.

b) change the path.

path is passed by reference so this can be changed directly. Assuming you create a module name ungoto:

```
ungoto_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
   // regular expression can be tightened
   if (preg_match('#^taxonomy/term/', $path)) {
     // Guessing that you are trying to 'display profiles' not display current 
     // users details, so global $user is not useful. 
     // Contextual filters says is is on the path. 
     // OP to do work to extract only the information needed.
     $user_details = $_GET[q];

     // Reset the path
     $path = $user_details . $path;   
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [hook_exit($destination)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_exit/7) to change the redirect.

- Create a new module. I use the Netbeans drupal-7 plugin to create .install, .info and .module files.
- Fill out the .info template.
- Implement hook_exit($destination). Call another drupal_goto(). Be careful that it can't create a redirect loop.

Hook Exit passes the destination address, and if you put a debugger on it you may be able to trace the call-stack to find another drupal_goto() that is causing the redirect.

Comment: The OP is interested to know how to stop the redirect, not how to redirect the user again. It is not said that redirecting the user to the first URL doesn't cause a loop.

Comment: This is changing the redirect, not redirecting again. You may only create redirect loop if you redirect to a page that redirects again. At least check to see that you are not redirecting to the current location. You cannot redirect twice in one http request.

Comment: The OP notices a redirect from mysite.com/user/*/taxonomy/term/* to mysite.com/taxonomy/term/* that he doesn't want. This means the solution should be avoiding that redirect is done. Your solution is redirecting from mysite.com/taxonomy/term/* to mysite.com/user/*/taxonomy/term/*. Isn't that a loop? The code that is causing the redirect (possibly PHP code) would probably cause the redirect again.

Comment: Probably not isn't it? He is targeting mysite.com/user/*/taxonomy/term/* and drupal has been programmed to redirect to mysite.com/taxonomy/term/*. Another goto() at the end would just undo the previous goto(). Of course it would be better to find the original goto(), but that could be impossible due to modules.

Comment: Looking at the code for drupal_goto() there is an even better option. hook_drupal_goto_alter() is called. This could have 2 uses a) breakpoint to find out where the drupal_goto() is coming from and b) change the path - passed as reference http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_drupal_goto_alter/7

Comment: drupal_goto() does header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, $http_response_code);  TRUE means that it replaces the previous setting of 'header'.

Comment: It cannot replace the previous value, since [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) calls [drupal_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7); after that, no other PHP code is executed, and the browser gets the first redirection header.

Comment: This redirected to 'abc' fine: function meetingclone_exit() {
  drupal_goto('abc');
}

Comment: But it doesn't avoid that, once loaded abc, another redirect is done. At each page request, Drupal is fully bootstrapped again. If some code is redirecting the first time, it would redirect the second time too, except in the case it saves a variable in the session, or something similar.

Comment: I would expect a conditional in your hook_exit(). if (preg_match(#taxonomy/term#, $destination) then drupal_goto(). Because drupal_goto causes drupal_exit I am not sure why drupal doesn't go into an infinite loop? It would be best to avoid this by directly using header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, $http_response_code). There is no session stuff. The Location: header is what tells the browser to redirect.

Comment: Let's try for the last time. At each new page request, Drupal is bootstrapped; this means that any static PHP variables, as well as global variables, are reset. For Drupal, there isn't any difference between serving a page because the user followed a link or because the browser has been redirected. The code that redirects from mysite.com/user/*/taxonomy/term/* to mysite.com/taxonomy/term/* cannot know another module redirected the user from mysite.com/taxonomy/term/* to mysite.com/user/*/taxonomy/term/*. The HTTP protocol is stateless by its own nature.